# MySQL Voting Table, Find most recent vote by each user on an entry, and count based on value

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, distinct, subquery

Working with a database structure I didn't create and hoping for some help on a simple MySQL query. I have a voting table `votes` with these fields:

`vote_id` = unique vote identifier

`item_id` = id of the entry voted on

`voter_id` = the id of the member who entered the vote

`vote_date` = the date of the vote

`vote` = the type of vote (1 or 2)

Each user can vote multiple times on a site entry specified by `item_id`. They can place a vote of 1 which is a "like" vote, or a vote of 2 which is an "unlike" vote. Each time they vote, a new record is created. I would like to be able to find the most recent `vote` value for each user on a particular `item_id` and then be able to actually SUM or COUNT the vote column IF the vote value is a "like" (value of 1)

For example

```
vote_id   item_id   voter_id   vote_date     vote
60        9         27         1273770151    1
153       9         45         1274896188    1
163       9         3          1274918584    1
164       9         3          1275021495    2
1051      9         181        1290839090    1
```

I want to get the newest `vote` values for each user, and then do a count of how many votes of 1 there are. In this case, the # would be 3

```
27  = 1
45  = 1
3   = 2
181 = 1
      3
```

Ideally once I have a "score" for each `item_id`, the query would be able to SUM the score of each one into a total # of ALL current "likes" on the site.

Thanks for any help with this. I did my best to find an answer to this by searching but nothing was exactly right.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EDIT:] I added values (1052, 10, 3, 1290839091, 1) to better exercise the problem, and had to add "item_id" to the sub-query that extracts *newest* votes.

---

Yay!  Finally a stackoverflow question I can actually answer!!!  I've been browsing around for a week looking for something short & sweet & up my alley.  Thanks for a fun SQL problem!

First, you need to extract the *newest* votes.  The combination of (voter_id, item_id, vote_date) better be unique for this approach to work!

```
SELECT
  voter_id, item_id, MAX(vote_date) AS vote_date
FROM
  votes
GROUP BY
  voter_id, item_id
```

Results:

```
+----------+---------+------------+
| voter_id | item_id | vote_date  |
+----------+---------+------------+
|        3 |       9 | 1275021495 |
|        3 |      10 | 1290839091 |
|       27 |       9 | 1273770151 |
|       45 |       9 | 1274896188 |
|      181 |       9 | 1290839090 |
+----------+---------+------------+
```

And then you need to join  the original table against these results.  A sub-select will do the job.  Notice how the query above is copy & pasted into the join below, but now it's given the name "tmp":

```
SELECT
  v.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    voter_id, item_id, MAX(vote_date) AS vote_date
  FROM
    votes
  GROUP BY
    voter_id, item_id
  ) tmp
INNER JOIN
  votes v ON (     v.vote_date = tmp.vote_date
               AND v.voter_id  = tmp.voter_id
               AND v.item_id   = tmp.item_id
  )
```

Results:

```
+---------+---------+----------+------------+------+
| vote_id | item_id | voter_id | vote_date  | vote |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+------+
|      60 |       9 |       27 | 1273770151 |    1 |
|     153 |       9 |       45 | 1274896188 |    1 |
|     164 |       9 |        3 | 1275021495 |    2 |
|    1051 |       9 |      181 | 1290839090 |    1 |
|    1052 |      10 |        3 | 1290839091 |    1 |
+---------+---------+----------+------------+------+
```

I trust you know what to do from here....  oh darn it, I can't help myself, this is too cute:

```
SELECT
  v.item_id, SUM(2 - v.vote) AS likes, SUM(v.vote - 1) AS dislikes
FROM (
  SELECT
    voter_id, item_id, MAX(vote_date) AS vote_date
  FROM
    votes
  GROUP BY
    voter_id, item_id
  ) tmp
INNER JOIN
  votes v ON (     v.vote_date = tmp.vote_date
               AND v.voter_id  = tmp.voter_id
               AND v.item_id   = tmp.item_id
  )
GROUP BY
  v.item_id
```

Results:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| item_id | likes | dislikes |
+---------+-------+----------+
|       9 |     3 |        1 |
|      10 |     1 |        0 |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Thanks Julius. This does make total sense, and thank you for writing it out in such detail, the only problem is, I can't get it to work :) This code seems to find the single most recent vote by each user on ALL item_ids. There are currently 127 distinct voters with 12000 votes on 4900 entries, this query only returns 127 results instead of the score for each of the 4900. Does that make any sense? Hopefully my original question is clear. Your last "results" box is what I'm after, but a row for each entry, AND the ability to sum the # of likes... THANK YOU.

Comment: Oops, yeah, I made a small mistake.  I've edited the answer.  Should work now!

Comment: This does the trick Julius, thank you very much for your help with this. The only final bonus would be the ability to sum the Likes column, but I can hopefully sort that out...

Comment: Add WITH ROLLUP at the bottom of the query?

Answer (score 0):

Unsure of the question, is this what you're looking for?

`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votes WHERE vote = '1' AND item_id = '9'`

Comment: Not really, I only want to the _newest_ vote for each voter_id. A user may have voted a 1, and then a 2 later. I don't want to consider that vote in the count. There are also _many_ item_ids so this query needs to find the "score" for each item_id. I'd love to be able to then SUM the total value of all scores, so a SUM of the COUNT.